# Doctrine ORM 2.1: Logging changes to Entity

Tags: events, orm, doctrine

I'm trying to log the specific changes to an Entity on an update.  I believe I understand how to use @PostUpdate but I'm not sure how to get all the entity changes:

`/** @PostUpdate */

public function onPostUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)

{

    1. Get all Entity Changes

    2. Log audit changes to the database

}`

It's the part in section 1 that I'm struggling with.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On postLoad store the entity, then get the difference on postUpdate.